# nginx + uwsgi + flask + selenium Selenium driver not opening

Tags: python, selenium, nginx, flask, uwsgi

my selenium code works fine if I run directly in local. But when I start Nginx and if code triggers selenium driver then it's not able to open.

```
DEBUG:selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection:POST http://127.0.0.1:45283/session {"capabilities": {"firstMatch": [{}], "alwaysMatch": {"browserNam
e": "chrome", "platformName": "any", "goog:chromeOptions": {"prefs": {"download.default_directory": "/home/cloud_sriniakhil/flaskapp/downloads", "downl
oad.prompt_for_download": false, "directory_upgrade": true, "safebrowsing.enabled": true}, "extensions": [], "args": ["--headless"]}}}, "desiredCapabil
ities": {"browserName": "chrome", "version": "", "platform": "ANY", "goog:chromeOptions": {"prefs": {"download.default_directory": "/home/cloud_sriniak
hil/flaskapp/downloads", "download.prompt_for_download": false, "directory_upgrade": true, "safebrowsing.enabled": true}, "extensions": [], "args": ["-
-headless"]}}}
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTP connection (1): 127.0.0.1:45283
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:http://127.0.0.1:45283 "POST /session HTTP/1.1" 500 357
DEBUG:selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection:Finished Request
```

It shows urllib3.connectionpool:http://127.0.0.1:45283 "POST /session HTTP/1.1" 500 357 but when i run normally in localhost i get status 200.
My guess is nginx is not allowing to use that port.

i am deploying my project first time on the cloud and any help would be really helpful Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:http://127.0.0.1:45283 "POST /session HTTP/1.1" 500 357
```

...implies that the *HTTP* `POST /session HTTP/1.1` returned *500 Internal Server Error*.

---

### 500 Internal Server Error

As per the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/500) *500 Internal Server Error* server error response code indicates that the server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request. Additionally, this error response is a generic response and this error indicates the server cannot find a better `5xx` error code to respond.

A bit more detailed error response like the 500 status code with more details about the request wouldhave helped us to debug the issue and suggest a canonical solution to prevent the error from happening again in the future.

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [502 Bad Gateway with DigitalOcean (gunicorn/nginx) using Selenium and Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60451310/502-bad-gateway-with-digitalocean-gunicorn-nginx-using-selenium-and-django/60453469#60453469)

Comment: I tried all those but still, I am getting the same error, I tried with uwsgi also but no luck still same